# solving $Lu = f$ numerically where $f$ is discontinuous

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am dealing with the second order differential equation

$-y''+p(x)y + q(x)y = r(x)$

on $0 \le x \le 1$ with boundary conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y(1) = 0.$

I am using the finite difference method to obtain a numerical solution for $y$.

However, my $r(x)$ is only continuous almost everywhere since it is defined as:

$r(x) = 0$ when $x \neq 1/2$ and $r(x) = 1$ when $x = 1/2$. Actually, the $1/2$ is arbitrary but it's any point inside the interval $[0,1]$.

Of course, if I run my numerical ODE solver, I will get an answer for $y$ given the discontinuous $r(x)$ that I have. But my question is, am I even allowed to use the finite difference method as usual to solve this problem numerically?

If you're curious as to how the $r(x)$ came about, the ODE above (with $q(x)=0$) is the adjoint problem to my original ode.

can anyone lead me to relevant references?
Thanks!

Comment: In some sense, numerical methods for these sorts of problems give approximations to a weak solution of the equation. Finite elements really do give approximate weak solutions (this is explicitly built into the construction of the method). Finite difference methods can be understood in the finite element framework with a certain amount of work, and so they also produce approximate weak solutions in a certain sense.

Comment: The weak formulation of your DE has no discontinuity involved at all: the integral of a smooth function multiplied with your $r$ does not "see" $x=1/2$, since this point has measure zero, so the integral is just zero. Thus when you convert your weak formulation back to a strong formulation, you right side becomes just zero. This means that your problem is really ill-posed, and in particular, as the mesh size of your finite difference method tends to zero, the actual contribution of the point $x=1/2$ will become smaller and smaller. (Actually, it will be zero unless $x=1/2$ is on the mesh.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may solve the finite-difference problem, but it is unlikely that you get convergence of any order higher than one. Finite volume methods are advised if coefficients or right-hand side is discontinuous.

Another way may be the following. Let $\mathcal L$ be your differential operator:
$$
\mathcal{L}y \equiv -y''(x) + p(x) y'(x) + q(x) y(x)
$$
and your right hand side has the form
$$
r(x) = a(x) + b(x) \theta(x).
$$
where $\theta(x)$ is the Heaviside theta function. I've moved the discontinuity to $x = 0$, but that should not matter.

Let's search for a solution in form
$$
y(x) = R(x) \theta(x) + S(x).
$$
with $R, S$ being smooth.

Differentiating the solution yields
$$\begin{aligned}
y'(x) &= R'(x) \theta(x) + R(x) \delta(x) + S'(x)\\
y''(x) &= R''(x) \theta(x) + \left[R(x) \delta(x)\right]' + S''(x).\end{aligned}
$$
So
$$
\mathcal{L}y = (\mathcal{L}R)\theta(x) + \mathcal{L}S + p(x)R(x)\delta(x)
-\left[R(x) \delta(x)\right]' = a(x) +b(x) \theta(x).
$$
Since $a(x)\delta(x) = a(0)\delta(x),\; (a(x)\delta(x))' = a(0)\delta'(x)$
$$
(\mathcal{L}R)\theta(x) + \mathcal{L}S + p(0)R(0)\delta(x)
-R(0)\delta'(x) = a(x) +b(x) \theta(x)
$$
the problem reduces to a pair of smooth problems
$$
\mathcal{L}S = a(x)\\
\mathcal{L}R = b(x)\\
R(0) = 0\\
R'(0) = 0.
$$
The condition $R'(0) = 0$ is required for the function $y(x)$ to have a continuous derivative. One can solve the Cauchy problem for $R(x)$ and then solve a boundary problem for $S$ with known boudnary conditions.

**Example**. Solve
$$
y''(x) + y(x) = \theta(x - 1/2), \quad x \in [0, 1]\\
y(0) = y(1) = 0
$$
Let's make a substitution
$$
y(x) = R(x) \theta\left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right) + S(x).
$$

Solving
$$
R'' + R = 1\\
R(1/2) = R'(1/2) = 0
$$
gives
$$
R = 2 \sin^2 \frac{1-2x}{4}.
$$
Solving 
$$
S'' + S = 0\\
S(0) = y(0) - R(0) \theta(-1/2) = y(0) = 0\\
S(1) = y(1) - R(1) \theta(1/2) = y(1) - R(1) = -2\sin^2 \frac{1}{4}\\
$$
gives
$$
S = -2 \csc (1) \sin^2 \left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \sin x
$$
The final solution is
$$
y = 2 \theta \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right) \sin ^2\left(\frac{1-2 x}{4}\right)-2 \sin ^2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \csc (1) \sin x
$$